# How to autosave a custom post type from the front end?

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, autosave

So the question is pretty straight forward.

How to autosave a custom post type from the front end?

Is there an easy way to go about this with  `WordPress`? I am hoping `WordPress` has an action hook that calls my `save_post_{my_CPT}` callback function to handle the autosave. If so, then how?

Another solution perhaps is using `JavaScript AJAX`... create an `AJAX` call every so often that inserts the current form data into the database. But this could be too messy, prompt for errors.

What do you guys think?